# No audio after installing ubuntu 11.10 & low screen resolution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, ubuntu-11.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10. I was using Windows XP earlier. After installing, when i tried to play music, there was no audio. Also the maximum screen resolution is 1024x768 while in XP it was 1440x900. I think i need to install drivers from intel but i gave up after unsuccessfully searching drivers for ubuntu for a whole day. Please kindly help.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate I think in an [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/)

Comment: There is AskUbuntu for that, but i can't flag this question to be migrated there.

Answer (score 0):

Audio format like MP3, mpeg are restrcited format. So, only the audio formats are not shipped with the Ubuntu. To play audio and video files you have to install ubuntu-restricted-extras.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/MP3) is the useful link for the installation of ubuntu-restricted

You can change resolution of the ubuntu desktop, system --> Preference ---> Monitor.